# Can i access MVC model properties in a separate js file referenced in the .cshtml file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding

I am working on an `MVC` project which uses model binding. I need to access the whole model in a `javascript` file which is referenced in the view page.
I tried JSON encoding the whole model inside a script tag in the view page.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    console.log(model);
```

which works fine.

In my case, the entire script has to stay in a separate page ie. Not inside the view page itself. How can I access the entire model from that script page?

A single property can be bound to a hidden input field, and the value can be accessed from js by its id i.e.:

```
<input type="hidden" id="modelObject" value="@model.property")/>
 var model = $("#modelObject").val();
```

I need the whole model in the js page. How can this can be achieved?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is my answer usefull for you?

Comment: check out the `src` attribute of the `script` element.

Answer (score 0):

Razor templates output text, which can typically be a "page" (html/css/js) served with a content type of text/html.  But you can serve other content types, like text/javascript, if you want.

First, create a controller action decorated with the `ActionName` attribute:

```
public class ScriptsController {
    [ActionName("model.js")]
    public ActionResult ModelJs() {
        var model = new Object();  // your actual model here.
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then you create your view, which is just like your `script` tag in your current page:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

make sure you remove the script element from your current page.

Then reference the new js view in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("model.js", "Scripts")"></script>
```

Comment: better to return Json from the controller instead of converting it with .Raw and Encode to Json in the view

Comment: "Better" must always be defined.

Comment: I am just always very hesitant to using Html.Raw as it renders unencoded data in the view, of course you have covered this with the Json.Encode, but why not just do that encoding on the server and pass the pure Json to the client, looks like a better separation of concerns to me, and it also makes sure developers do not use Html.Raw incorrectly/insecure when you just agree not to use it at all.

Comment: I think either method will work fine.  Returning json from the controller is great for the simplicity.  Returning json from the view is great if you need to customize what gets returned.. like say, add some functions to the file, or encapsulate the json in a function.  Either way, what I most disagree with is the idea that just because something has the potential for misuse people believe it shouldn't be used at all.  Dangerous things should be used appropriately, and not misused.  But `Html.Raw` has a purpose and an acceptable use.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a constructor for your JavasScript model and then instantiate that with razor code.

For example:

Model

```
public class Car{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Fuel { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript file in module pattern, but you can use something else as well:

```
var car = (function(jsonModel){
    var runs = "My " + jsonModel.Brand + " runs on " + jsonModel.Fuel;
    return {
        Runs : runs
    }
    });
```

Razor view

```
@model Car

<!--load the javascript file somewhere-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var myFord = new car(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)) );
            alert(myFord.Runs);
        });
</script>
```

[.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BDhIb7) I could not add an external javascript file, but you will probably get the point

Although I should say that using @Html.Raw is not recommended as it makes you vulnerable to XSS attacks (read more on the internet after a search). It is better to return the JSON object from your controller.

**Edit**

Here is an example how to use the JsonResult on [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qJZLm8)
controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Car()
    {
        return Json(new Car("ford","gasoline"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

razor view JS to get the json result and instantiate your JS module

```
$(function(){
            var model = $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Car","Home")",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                var myFord = new car(response);
                alert(myFord.Runs);
            });
        });
```

Comment: This answer does not address the OPs question.

Comment: I think it does, as I read it the OP wants to have an entire model send to a JS file, as I mentioned I could not reference a separate file, that is why the JavaScript was inline in the Razor view, but you can of course place this in a separate file and then include the file from the view